# How to set default value for NULL property in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to set default value for all my `NULL` objects. 
Here's what I have

```
private setDisplayAmount(summaries: summary[]): void {
    summaries.map(t => {
        // do some magic, and then...
        this.setDefaultValueForEmptyAmounts(t);
    });
}

private setDefaultValueForEmptyAmounts(summary: Summary): void {
    Object.values(summary.displayAmounts).map(property => property || 0);
}
```

I've no idea why `setDefaultValueForEmptyAmounts` doesn't work properly...

This will work but is less esthetic:

```
private setDisplayAmount(summaries: summary[]): void {
    summaries.map(t => {
        // do some magic, and then...
        t.displayAmounts = {
            OneAmount: t.oneAmt || 0,
            TwoAmount: t.twoAmt || 0,
            // ... for all properties
        };

    });
}
```

Comment: Object.values(...).map(...) doesn't set values, only results in a array with the values

Comment: So how can I fix it?

Comment: You probably want to change your `map`s to `forEach`es, and instead of doing `Object.values().map()`, you want `Object.keys(x).forEach(k => x[k] = ...)`.  Or just use for loops, if you don't understand how these functional programming methods work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using map operations, you should always return something. 
But you could use forEach.

```
summaries.forEach(summary => {
    Object.keys(summary).forEach(key => {
    summary[key] = summary[key] || 0;
    });
});
```